# sorting tuples by index in lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

So I've been trying to implement a sort function that sorts a list of tuples by the index of the tuples in the list, what I want the function to do is to work exactly like the following:

```
def sort(list):
    for item in list:
        list.sort(key=lambda tuple: tuple[1])
    return list
```

this returns

```
[('asdasd', 1), ('test', 2), ('34', 3), ('testtt', 5), ('ahj', 12)]
```

when

```
listtest = [("test",2),("testtt",5),("ahj",12),("asdasd",1),("34",3)]
```

is called.

The reason for me simply not using this is because I'm trying to learn how to implement algorithms into programming languages, since I come from a background in mathematics.

The algorithm I made works as following (example is shown with list containing just elements, not tuples)

```
def my_sort(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        j = i-1
        key = list[i]
        while (list[j] > key) and (j >= 0):
            list[j+1] = list[j]
            j -= 1
        list[j+1] = key
    return list
```

which does sort the elements by index. Now for the part where I want to sort tuples by index, what I have so far is:

```
def sort_tuples(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        j = i - 1
        key = list[i][1] #returns the index of tuple i
        while (list[j][1] > key) and (j >= 0): #compares the 2nd tuples index with the first tuples index
            list[j+1] = list[j]
            j -= 1 
        key = list[j+1][1] # <----- problem?
    return list
```

when running this it returns

```
[('test', 2), ('test', 2), ('testtt', 5), ('testtt', 5), ('ahj', 12)]
```

Comment: First, try not to use "list" as a variable name, "list" is a built-in name, so your code is confusing

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep `list[i]` in order to reinsert it at the jth index :

```
def sort_tuples(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        j = i - 1
        list_i = list[i]
        key = list[i][1] 
        while (list[j][1] > key) and (j >= 0):
            list[j+1] = list[j]
            j -= 1
        list[j+1] = list_i
    return list

print sort_tuples([("test",2),("testtt",5),("ahj",12),("asdasd",1),("34",3)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Zen of Python states: if some code is easy-to-read and working, do not change it (It is good job. It is good.).

```
def mysort(myiter):
    result = []
    for i in myiter:
        result[i[1]] = i[0]
    return tuple(result)
```

is the most readable and elegant snippet.